# ASP.NET C# Handling an Image

Tags: asp.net, image

Similar to one of my other questions, but I need clarification.

I have a web application where multiple users will be on at the same time.  In the app, an image, which is in one of the app folders, will be drawn on like below, saved, and then added to the image control on the page.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Assets/img/timegrid.jpg");
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5); 
//draw on image
graphics.DrawLine(p, aPoint, bPoint); 

//save new image
image.Save(Server.MapPath("~") + "/Assets/img/newtimegrid.jpg");
imgGrid.ImageUrl = "~/Assets/img/newtimegrid.jpg";
```

Each user's new image will look different.  However, I'm worried that User A will see User B's newtimegrid.jpg instead of his own since every user is saving to the same filename.  I've heard of using a generic Image Handler and I've read some of the solutions here, but I still don't understand how to use it, or how to call it if I made one, or if this is even a solution to my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to keep userID in the session and use this id in the path to uniquely identifying the path of image for each user image path.

You can first check if path already exists for user.

```
string strDirPath = Server.MapPath("~") + "/Assets/img/ + Session["UserID"].ToString();

if(Directory.Exists(strDirPath))
{
     Bitmap image = new Bitmap(strDirPath + "\\" + timegrid.jpg");
     //your code here
}
else
{
     DirectoryInfo CreateDirectory(strDirPath);
     Bitmap image = new Bitmap(strDirPath + "\\" + timegrid.jpg");
     //your code here
}
```

Comment: Yea, I thought about that, and I may end up doing so.  I just wanted to see if using an image handler would solve it.

Comment: you can put id in image name if you expect only one image per user